# Extra spacing in NavigationBarTitle in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a detail view that displays with an absurd amount of spacing and I can't figure out why.

```swift
    struct MessageDetailView : View {
    var friend: Friend
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<friend.messages.count) { message in
                    Text(self.friend.messages[message])
                        .modifier(textBubbleModifier())
                }
                }.navigationBarTitle(
                    Text(self.friend.name))
        }
    }
}
```

The Friend struct is pretty simple:

```swift
struct Friend: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var messages: [String] = [""]
}

let friends: [Friend] = [
    Friend(name: "Mark Zuckerberg", messages: ["Let's keep things private between you and I, shall we?", "I can keep a secret", "I definitely won't sell all your data"])
```

Attached are two images. One from the simulator with the erroneous spacing and one from the canvas view, without. Any ideas? It might just be an Xcode bug.

[Simulator Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlyUV.png)
[Canvas View Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBBwC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canvas doesn't know that the view may be pushed to a `NavigationView` or not and displays correctly. But in runtime it's pushed and you're using a `NavigationView` as well in your detail view. Try unwrapping your content from the `NavigationView` in the detail view's body. So it will look like below code:

```
var body: some View {
  List {
    ForEach(0..<friend.messages.count) { message in
      Text(self.friend.messages[message])
        .modifier(textBubbleModifier())
    }
    }.navigationBarTitle(
      Text(self.friend.name))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mo, that did it!